# Yii jQuery ajax on success returns a huge link in a "data" variable before normal response

Tags: jquery, ajax, amazon-web-services, yii

In my Yii website I'm using jQuery ajax to extract some data from the Amazon AWS service.
Everything works fine except an ajax response. In my controller action I get data from the Amazon like that:

```
$jdata = $this->amazonProxyRequest();
```

After that, the `$jdata` contains rows of associative arrays with the all data I need.

For example, I need now to extract the first row and 'echo' it as an ajax json response. I do:

```
$jt_data = CJSON::encode($jdata[0]);
```

The `$jt_vata` variable contains a valid JSON now, and according to the debugger, I'm pasting, it is

```
"{"id":"1","author":"Leo Tolstoy","title":"War and Peace (Cambridge World Classics) Critical Edition (Annotated) (Complete Works of Leo Tolstoy \/ Complete Works of Leo Tolstoi)","publisher":"Cambridge World Classics","isbn":"","year_published":"2010-11-30"}"
```

So far so good. Then in my view I want to use this data. Just for testing purpose, I ask 'success' option to fire an alarm with the `data` variable I've passed to the method.

```
'onblur'=> CHtml::ajax(array(
     'url'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('book/searchAmazon'),
     'type'=>'post',                                                        
     //'dataType'=>'json',
     'data'=>array('title' => 'js:this.value'),
     'success' => "js:function(data)
                {
                   alert(data);
                }",
     'error' => "function(data, status){ alert(status); }",
 ))
```

If I uncomment `'dataType'=>'json'` I will get a `parsererror`, and I do know why. The `data` variable in the `success` function **does** contain my JSON data, but there is also an entirely huge GET request string to the Amazon Web Service appended before. So the `alert(data)` show the alert containing

```
http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=MyAccessKey&AssoSignature=
... etc ...
DrJzWb73c08V5yffKUkFOu63Y4w%2FtIEc%2FtlVVjBKrUY%3D{"id":"1","author":
"Leo Tolstoy","title":"War and Peace (Cambridge World Classics) 
Critical Edition (Annotated) (Complete Works of Leo Tolstoy \/ Complete Works of Leo
Tolstoi)","publisher":"Cambridge World Classics","isbn":"","year_published":
"2010-11- 30"}
```

Even if I don't do

```
echo CJSON::encode($jdata[0]);
```

in the controller, I still get the GET string in my alarm, but without any JSON appended. The only way to get rid of the long string is to comment

```
$jdata = $this->amazonProxyRequest();
```

which is not acceptable, of course.

**QUESTION:**

I would appreciate so much if you tell me where does this link come from?

I tried to figure this out by myself, but I haven't succeed.

Comment: pls provide the function amazonProxyRequest(). I suspect somewhere in the function you echoing the url

Comment: Thank you so much! Yup, I've found `echo $request` in another method (not in amazonProxyRequest() which private, but in one from a 'vendor' class...)